# Phonegap 2.4.0 with Android 4.2 - strange double click behaviour

Tags: android, cordova, onclick, double-click

I'm using phonegap 2.4.0 to create an Android and iOS App.

Now I recognized that the onclick event in links is fired twice inside the Android App using Android 4.2.2 on a Nexus 4 device, like a double click (althoug I tapped it only once!).

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).append('test'); return false;" style="some styles...">some text</a>
```

libs in use:

- jquery 1.9.1
- jquery mobile 1.3.0 (rc)
- jquery ui 1.10.0
- jquery touch punch 0.2.2
- phonegap 2.4.0

After I clicked (or tapped) the link on my Nexus 4 (Android 4.2.2) the string 'test' is appended twice inside the app.

This does NOT happen when I test it as mobile web app directly in the android browser.

It also works on my Samsung S3 (Android 4.1.2) inside the app.
No problem on iPhones, too.

Anyone else recognized this strange behavior? (and maybe was able to fix it? ;-) )

Answer (score 15):

Using a temporary solution from [scirra.com](http://www.scirra.com/forum/google-nexus-jellybean-issue_topic57145.html)

```
last_click_time = new Date().getTime();
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    click_time = e['timeStamp'];
    if (click_time && (click_time - last_click_time) < 1000) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    last_click_time = click_time;
}, true);
```

Comment: I've implemented several versions of the same hack, this one is beautiful - don't know why I never solved it on the document click level, thanks for re-sharing it :)

Comment: great solution, I had a glitch because if detecting a "ghost" click the button remains in an active state so I added $('.ui-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-active'); after preventDefault();

Comment: Only inconvenience with this is you have to set last_click_time in every single click event in your code.

Comment: It is not an awesome hack. Well, it might be working for you, but it's still a frigging hack, and a not very reliable one as I noticed that the time between the firing of events varies wildly. 
I wonder If Kaan's solution does not work at all.. I'll try it out

Comment: Don't use this hack! This causes issues with Android 6+ and almost all new web browsers. My buttons become unclickabe. Was really hard to find out that this code is the troublemaker!

Answer (score 2):

I handled my similar situation very closely to Soulwax's solution, however I didn't want to hinder fast clicks by the user by keeping track of time intervals. Instead, I simply track the event type in the link's data object and if it's trying to handle a click immediately after a touchstart I ignore that call.

```
$('.link').on('touchstart click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  //Prevent against handling a click immediately after touchstart.
  if(e.type == "click" && $(this).data("lastTouch") == "touchstart"){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
  $(this).data("lastTouch", e.type);

  $('.nav-bar').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of these double/multiple clicks are malfunctioning hardware accelerations, I'm experiencing simultaneous clicks + propagation's, propagation's are easy to prevent, however since third argument of addEventListener isn't respected in my case, I can't prevent double click even with the previously answered code, here is what I ended up using

```
function cw(event) // click wall
{ try {
    click_time_cw = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (click_time_cw && (click_time_cw - last_click_time_cw) < 350) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        add_log('prevented misclick [CW] '+(click_time_cw - last_click_time_cw));
        return true;
    }
    last_click_time_cw = click_time_cw;
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
} catch(e){ add_alert(e,"stpr"); } }
```

you also have to initialize last_click_time_cw=(new Date()).getTime() somewhere

this is an example onclick:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="if(cw(event)) return true; onclick_logic()">something</button>
```

it might seem like a lot of work and an unpleasant/ugly fix, but click problems have been haunting me for months, it seems like this is what I should've done from the begining

Answer (score 0):

My fix was a little bit different. I've used `touchend` instead `click` event listener, because `click` doesn't fire each time it's needed. Let's say you click a button, the click event listener is fired, but if you click that button again it is not.

It happens to any kind of DOM element. My environment is:

- jQuery 1.9.1;
- jQM 1.3.2;
- Phonegap 3.5.0-0.21.14.

Here is my code:

```
if (window.cordova) {
    // hack to avoid double tap
    var lastTapTime = new Date().getTime();
    function tryToAvoidDoubleTap(e){
        var tapTime = e["timeStamp"];
        if (tapTime && (tapTime - lastTapTime) < 300) {
            // prevent double tap to happen
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            // jQM button handling
            if ($('.ui-btn').length)
                $('.ui-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
            return false;
        }
        lastTapTime = tapTime;
    }

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("touchend", tryToAvoidDoubleTap, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue, but my app/game *needed* the user to be able to double tap, on touchstart. So the scirra solution mentioned above wasn't usable as a required delay of 500 or 1000 ms kills the doubletap.

After some digging I noticed a difference between the first (user) tap and the second (bug) tap:

```
event.originalEvent.touches
```

isn't available in the second bug tap.
So I wrote this bug detection helper which solved my case:

```
function isDoubleTapBug (e) {
  // only handle touch events (in case your listener works on mouse events too)
  if (!'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)) 
    return false;
  if (!e.originalEvent.touches) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true; // indicate to caller that it's a bug
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then in your listener, do this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
  if (isDoubleTapBug(e))
    return false;
  // now do your actual event handling stuff...      
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code, if (!'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement))  should be if (!'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)  if im not wrong