# jQuery mobile "collapsible content" in PhoneGap on android 4.2

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

I'm developing a PhoneGap App with jQuery "collapsible content" elements. Now I'm testing the app under Android 4.2.2 on a Nexus 7 device and I have a problem with the expand/collapse event. The element expand and collapse immediately after the touch event. If I tap and hold the element for a second the collapse or expand event works.

It's very strange because it works under iOS (iPhone 5, iPad) and on Android 2.3.5 (HTC Desire HD)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be seeing the same double-click bug as this. [Phonegap 2.4.0 with Android 4.2 - strange double click behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982864/phonegap-2-4-0-with-android-4-2-strange-double-click-behaviour)

You can try the solution proposed in the link.