# Which scroll is best for Android: PhoneGap

Tags: android, css, html, cordova

I'm going to implementing design for android application using HTML5 and css , previously in one application I had used Iscroll but iscroll have lots of issues like flickring and double tap) so I dont want to use it any more so want to discuss you all (phonegap android developer that which scroll should be best to use in my android application so that it does not create any issue.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not use: `overflow-y:scroll`on the container/Div that you need to scroll?

Comment: iScroll works great - even with JQM. Where did you notices flickers? Concerning the double-clicks: Did you knew that Android has issues with that? There is a temporary solution to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982864/phonegap-2-4-0-with-android-4-2-strange-double-click-behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Use `overthrow.js`.. it works fine with android.. I have implemented.. 
Simple overflow property doesnt support in android < 4

Comment: Hi amss can you pls refer me any link regarding this and scroll name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TouchScroll](https://github.com/davidaurelio/TouchScroll).There are some examples [here](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/scroll-div.htm).